# Is it possbile to load module compiled under kernel 2.6.x to a system with kernel 3.8.x

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, compiling, modules

I have Marvell USB wireless driver src which only supports up to kernel 2.6.8. Now my system is Ubuntu 13.04 with kernel 3.8 and I can not compile the src under the new kernel anymore. I found the asm/system.h and the netlink.h changed in newer kernel.

So I want to ask if I can compile the module under the 2.6.x kernel and then just copy the .ko file to the new system and load it?

Comment: Short answer: no. What device do you need to have supported?

Comment: A Marvell 88W8782U wireless module

Comment: OK, I see now. You don't have the original driver. Did you try to run your 3.x kernel to just see whether it works? Chances are, the default kernel already supports your hardware.